# Isolated > medial substitutions in FontForge

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I've been working on a font for a fictional language (Ta'agra from Skyrim) and I'm having issues getting the substitutions to work. It's supposed to be written similarly to Arabic where each letter connects and has an initial, medial, terminal, and solo form. I've made lookup tables specifying " isol @ | isol @ (med) " so that if there are two letters typed, the first will become an initial form and the second a medial. In another table I've put " med | isol @(med) " so that anything typed after a medial form will also be medial. However, when I type it will come up as initial, medial, initial, medial... I have no idea how to create the lookup tables I need.

In summary, I just need to know how to make it so that as I type isolated forms, they will turn into initial and medial forms as needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried opening an actual Arabic font and taking a look at what its substitution rules look like?

Comment: I tried opening one that i downloaded from online, but didn't see any lookup tables in Fontforge. Maybe it would only show up if i got a .sfd Arabic font file but idk where I'd find that.

Comment: I got an Arabic font to open but there are no tables. It's different there because there are unicode tags for each letter form, whereas I'm working with an English keyboard.